# STM32 sim 7500 module

Tags: stm32

Previously, i say sorry for my bad english grammar.

I have a project on stm32 with sim module 7500e (because i need post https)
The program works properly. But, after my board was successfully sent post https in 40 or 41 times, the program gets stucked (cannot send post https again), cause I was monitoring the program by using serial terminal.
For anticipate it, i press the reset button and the program can send post https again.

My question is how to reset board without press the reset button (or automatically in program) ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't reset the board - that's silly, and likely problematic for whatever purpose you are actually trying to achieve.  Instead, understand the actual cause of the issue and fix it.

Comment: Okey, i try to know what is the problem. Btw thanks for your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happened because of your connection, TCP-Ip or UDP needs to Renew after 40 sec , you just need to open sucket TCP or UDP after that closed, so you need to check connection if that closed open that again.

Comment: thank youu very much

Comment: you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In the [SIM75XXX hardware design document](http://www.mt-system.ru/sites/default/files/docs/simcom/docs/SIM7500/sim7500a_sim7500e_sim7500je_sim7500jc_sim7500v_sim7500sa_hardware_design_v1.07.pdf), Page 19, an interface introduced, which is probably the answer to your problem (it changes the state of PWRKEY to high):

[image]

And if you can not reset the module with making the ***PWRKEY*** pin state to high, Try the the emergency solution, which is explained on page 21 of the same document (AKA changing the state of ***RESET*** pin to zero):

[image]

**PS.** Read the datasheets!